# How to call unmanaged code in ASP.NET website and host it in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++, iis

I have created a C++ dll.  It works fine and does the job.

I have created methods in asp.net that call the methods in C++ dll. DLL path is absolute. It works fine too.

I then published the website onto a folder and hosted the website on IIS.  I get an error message

```
Exception Details: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FilesCreator.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Please suggest what I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: This is a duplicate question by the same author. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247907/asp-net-c-does-not-work-under-classic-application-pool-mode

Comment: i really need a solution, may be my previous question was unclear as i didn't get any answer there

Comment: Is the FilesCreator.dll copied into the /bin folder of the website?

Comment: yep. i have used absolute and relative paths, yet no luck.

Comment: Can you show us one of your DLLImport statements? Also, there were some comments to your previous question, asking for more information. You haven't given us enough information to help you debug your problem. You'll have to provide more details if you want us to help.

Comment: i just noticed the comments now.   [DllImport("c:\\User\\bin\\FilesCreator.dll")]
  public static extern void SetText(int h, String s, string name);
}

Comment: just to confirm, it's not related to a missing dependent dll right? as it works perfectly in VS

Answer (score 1):

Did you confirm that the authenticated user of the application pool which is running your app has the appropriate permissions to read and execute the DLL?

Try adding permissions for the user who is running the application pool for IIS7. For IIS6, if you are using anonymous authentication trying giving permission to the IIS anonymous user as configured in your Web Site settings.
See [here for IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154735/understanding-iis6-permissions-acl-and-identity-how-can-i-restrict-access) and [here for IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532079/iis7-folder-permissions-for-web-application).

Comment: I added Everyone group in the security tab of the folder with full control. That should have worked right?

Comment: Not necessarily. Edited my answer, above.

Comment: is using network service with no impersination. i have added network service and the logged in user in security tab of the foler which contains the DLL and I given the two users full access on the folder. yet i experience no success... what am i missing?

Comment: Is this IIS7? If so, it runs as a 64-bit process so perhaps there is an issue if you're trying to call a function in a 32-bit EXE? Can you confirm that they are both targeting the same architecture?