# DllImport - function not returning the correct value in ASP.Net when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, com, dllimport

I have a web service that I need to make a call to a function in some unmanaged code, I import the dll like:

```
     class myClass
    {
      [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
      public static extern int FetchMyData(int DataType, int DataIndex);
    }
```

The web page does an AJAX callback to a WebService which calls the imported function like:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public int FetchData(int IndexValue)
    {
      return  myClass.FetchMyData(DATA_TYPE, IndexValue);
    }
```

When I run this from VisualStudio using the development IIS Express, everything works fine, and the function returns a positive integer. However, when I deploy to my local IIS, the function always returns -1. It doesn't even throw an exception which seems a bit odd.

Things I have tried but didn't make any difference:

- added the "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" to the parent directory with full permissions
- set the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" property to **True**

**EDIT**

After further investigation and help from the various comments below it became clear that the issue here was not the function failing, rather a permissions related issue with what the dll function was doing, namely accessing a Memory Mapped File. I have created [this follow-up post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363839/opening-a-memory-mapped-file-causes-filenotfoundexception-when-deployed-in-iis) which replicates the core problem with sample code.

Comment: Did you ask [permissions to execute unmanaged code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0313z05(v=vs.90).aspx), see [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252738/how-to-call-unmanaged-code-in-asp-net-website-and-host-it-in-iis) for more details (assuming that unmanaged code doesn't access something that needs more rights than what granted to ASP.NET user).

Comment: Maybe you should look into the function code?

Comment: Thanks @Adriano - I hadn't asked for any permissions. I added the code from the link but this didn't make any noticeable difference.

Comment: @Andrey - the function code runs fine when using via IIS Express, so I doubt the problem is with the function.

Comment: @Fly_Trap check also _"...assuming that unmanaged code doesn't access something that needs more rights than what granted to ASP.NET user."_);

Comment: I have tried using the local Administrator account for the application pool identity, so this should overcome any permissions required by the function. Still no luck though.

Comment: @Fly_Trap I don't understand how you draw this conclusion. Never I heard that pinvoke behaves this way, if something is not working it will throw exception, but it will never produce some made up result instead of actually calling something. Most probably the function actually returns -1 and there are lots of reasons it can not work on IIS.

Comment: I take your point @Andrey, it does follow that the function _is_ getting called which is why there is no exception thrown. The function is a C function designed to return an integer stored in memory (which is updated by another process). I would have though though that by giving the DefaultAppPool the identity of the local Administrator account, then permission issues would be negated.

Comment: @Fly_Trap the whole setup is a little strange, how do you share memory between processes? Actually this kind of tricks are not very web hosting friendly, because web server usually tries to isolate web apps as much as possible and give them minimal rights (and other reasons). I would consider some interprocess communication in some form.

Comment: Its some old C applications I'm trying to interrogate. I know that IIS does try to isolate web applications from this sort of activity. I wasn't even sure if what I was attempting to do was even going to be possible, however, I did get some results in a friendly "access all areas" debug environment, so it follows that I should be able to  do it in a production environment if set up correctly. I'm going to attempt to debug the C++ function from the web application to see if that helps. This is totally uncharted territory for me though!

Comment: I have not been able to actively debug the C function, however, I have looked at the code. There is an return code of -1 if a call to `OpenFileMapping` returns a NULL.  I think this is what may be happening when deployed in IIS. I tried changing the Identity to my domain user name after reading [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/e621a06f-330a-48df-b057-74ca746b0bd4/memory-mapped-file-use-in-iis-fails)  thread but it didn't work.