# Opening a Memory Mapped File causes FileNotFoundException when deployed in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, ipc, memory-mapped-files

Following the code example from [this](http://gunnarpeipman.com/2009/06/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files/) website, I created a windows console application that creates a mapped memory file:

```
        using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("myFile", 24))
        {
            var bytes = new byte[24];
            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                bytes[i] = (byte)(65 + i);

            using (var writer = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, bytes.Length))
            {
                writer.WriteArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Run memory mapped file reader before exit");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

in a new asp.net web application I read the MMF using the code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sOutput = "";

        using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("myFile"))
        {
            using (var reader = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 24))
            {
                var bytes = new byte[24];
                reader.ReadArray<byte>(0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                    sOutput += (char)bytes[i] + " ";

            }
        }

        Response.Write(sOutput);
    }
```

In the development IIS Express the file is read as expected and the page displays the data from the mapped memory file.

However, When deployed to IIS I get the exception `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` at the location`MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("myFile")`

I tried changing the app pool identity to the same as the one running the MMF console application but this does didn't work.

Comment: Where is myFile located?

Comment: Is the ISAPI module installed on the production IIS?

Comment: In `Page_Load` you calling `MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting`. But do you have `MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew` method call in web application?

Comment: The `CreateNew` is called in the console application that creates the MMF. While the console app is running you can access the MMF from another process. This is the case when using IIS Express, but not standard IIS

Comment: ISAPI module _is_ already installed.

Comment: I assume the IIS Express and the IIS reside in different computers, with different permissions?  Is the IIS app running under the same account as the console app that creates the MMF?  Seems like the IIS is not permitted to see your MMF.

Comment: Both versions of IIS are on same computer, and run as the same identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "Global\\" prefix to the mapName. That is the only way it worked for me.
When we try to access shared memory created in the first process it runs in a different security context and shared memory objects are not visible unless they are created in the global namespace.

This is the code that worked for me. I used CreateOrOpen in a WinForm application and I used OpenExisting in an IIS process:

```
mSec = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
mSec.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\\MmfName", 100, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite, MemoryMappedFileOptions.None, mSec, HandleInheritability.Inheritable);

mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Global\\\MmfName");
```

Comment: I changed the code slightly to `MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("Global\\myFile",MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl,System.IO.HandleInheritability.None)` and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

If Inter Process Communication (IPC) is what you are trying to achieve, you could use WCF with a Named Pipe Binding. You gain a lot of simplicity at the cost of some performance.

Comment: Since my original post this is actually the road I have gone down, and it works very well.

Comment: This is a workaround not a solution. It be wrong to accept this as the answer as it would not help anyone else who may need a solution to this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For non physical file, there are two cases,

1. File is deleted after your process exits.
2. IIS does not run in same user as your console process, IIS runs in little restricted mode, so unless you create File with added security to allow process to access your service.

You will have to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267529(v=vs.110).aspx this constructor with following security.

```
        MemoryMappedFileSecurity mSec = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity ();
        mSec.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
            MemoryMappedFileRights .FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

And then try to access it from IIS with same security.

Comment: The default folder is somewhere in \windows\system32 or \windows\system32\inetsrv. You need to specify the full path, as this answer indicates, or call Server.MapPath("~/myFile.txt") to calculate it based on your web application root.

Comment: myFile is just the name of the memory mapped file, it doesn't have an accessible physical location on disk afaik, also, the myFile reference is created by another windows process (in my example its just a small console app). When the website is run in IIS Express it can access the mapped memory location fine, its when I set Visual Studio to use the local IIS this is when it fails.

Comment: Memory mapped file has to be a physical location on disk, where have you read that it doesn't have to be? "File" means it is a physical location on disk, otherwise you anyway have memory.

Comment: I'm using non persisted memory mapped file described   [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) "The CreateNew and CreateOrOpen methods create a memory-mapped file that is not mapped to an existing file on disk."

Comment: Still no joy. I created the MMF to run in the context of `NetworkService` and set the Identity of the IIS worker process to the same but I still get the `Unable to find the specified file.` exception.

Comment: Did you add security as I recommended? Also one you sure your console program is not closed before IIS tries to access the MMF.

Comment: (1) Set MemoryMappedFileSecurity as Akash said, (2) In IIS the mapName has to have prefix "Global\". Example, yor provider creates "Globlal\TEST" then inside IIS works "Globlal\TEST".