# C# Memory Mapped Files, app is hang on. What's wrong?

Tags: c#, winforms, ipc, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to write simple sender/receiver class for IPC with Memory Mapped Files.
So problem in my code, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
[Serializable]
public struct MessageData
{
    public int PID;
    public IntPtr HWND;
    public string ProcessName;
    public string ProcessTitle;
}

....

public static class MMF
{
    private const int MMF_MAX_SIZE = 4096;  // allocated memory for this memory mapped file (bytes)
    private const int MMF_VIEW_SIZE = 4096; // how many bytes of the allocated memory can this process access

    public static void Write()
    {
        var security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
        // Create a SecurityIdentifier object for "everyone".
        SecurityIdentifier everyoneSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(everyoneSid, MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\mmf1", MMF_MAX_SIZE, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream mStream = mmf.CreateViewStream(0, MMF_VIEW_SIZE))
            {

                var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
                MessageData msgData = new MessageData();
                msgData.HWND = p.MainWindowHandle;
                msgData.PID = p.Id;
                msgData.ProcessName = p.ProcessName;
                msgData.ProcessTitle = p.MainWindowTitle;

                // serialize the msgData and write it to the memory mapped file
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(mStream, msgData);
                mStream.Flush();
                mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // sets the current position back to the beginning of the stream

                //MessageBox.Show("Done");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I try test this code from main app form:

```
    ...
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MMF.Write();
    }
```

And process in Visual Studio 2015 Community hangs on. Process run, but form interface is not responding. I can only pause or stop process. This is stops on `using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("Global\\mmf1", ...` string.

I'm assuming that the app can't create the file, but there is no any exceptions.

So, if I change map name to "mmf1" (without "Global" prefix) all is OK, app works fine. But as far, as I know from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827313/6935496) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Prefixing the file mapping object names with "Global\" allows processes to communicate with each other even if they are in different terminal server sessions.

If I understand right, prefix "Global\" is needed to interact my memory-mapped file with any application, regardless of the privileges with which they are running.

Especially since I'm trying to set the file access permissions for "everyone".

**UPD.** This code tested on Win 7 / Win 8.1 x64. Result is same.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: Thanks for response, but I haven't any anti-mailware soft on developers PC. And are users of this program must switch off antiviruses too, to this app works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run Visual Studio as Administrator in order to create memory mapped files using the "Global\" prefix.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion if starting VS as admin still fails opening a memorymappedfile in the global namespace with an UnauthorizedAccess exception?  Thanks...